# zsh completion: make sshrc behave like ssh

Tags: ssh, zsh, autocomplete

I'm using the `sshrc` package and its eponymous command to make the remote machine's shell source the contents of my local .sshrc file upon SSH login.
However, I really like zsh's host autocompletion (based on the `~/.ssh/{config,authorized_keys}` and `/etc/hosts` files).

Aliasing ssh to sshrc won't trick zsh (seems like it resolves the alias before loading completion configs).
I have been trying to mess around with zsh's conf, e.g. copying `/usr/share/zsh/5.3.1/functions/_ssh` to `_sshrc`, editing said file and renaming its *_ssh()* function... no luck.

Would appreciate any pointers as I've got a few thousand hosts in my ssh config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me using `zsh 5.4.2`

```
$ PS1='%% ' zsh -f
% rm ~/.zcompdump
% autoload -U compinit && compinit
% compdef sshrc=ssh
% sshrc ...
```

under the minimal configuration of `zsh -f`. This may be thwarted by your shell configuration; in that case you'll need to bisect your configuration to see what's screwing up what.

This trick was found by looking at the `_ssh` completion which shows for `slogin` an equality with `ssh`:

```
% grep compdef $fpath[-1]/_ssh
#compdef ssh slogin=ssh scp ssh-add ssh-agent ssh-keygen sftp ssh-copy-id
%
```

Comment: Works indeed, I will tailor your solution to my specific configuration. Thanks!